# iOS 7 XCode 5 - UIAlertView with TextField - How to pull text into a Label or NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

```
UIAlertView *alertViewChangeName=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Change Name" message:@"What is your teacher's name?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alertViewChangeName.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alertViewChangeName show];
```

I am just looking to retrieve the input from the textbox and place it within a UILabel or an NSString to later use and/or manipulate.

Comment: This is it, `[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;`

Comment: Create a textfield and set that text field with alertView text field instance with below code..... .........                                         

UITextField *yourTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
yourTextField.delegate = self;

You can also access delegates of textfield by setting delegate as above

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to invoke `UIAlertView's` delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
     NSString *test = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the `-textFieldAtIndex:` method on UIAlertView to get your Textfield. e.g:

```
UIAlertView *alert = ...
UITextField *textInput = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textInput.text = ...

// get user input
NSString *userInput = textInput.text;
```